# PHP remove duplicates in foreach after substr results

Tags: php, foreach

How can I remove the duplicates after my substr output in the foreach loop? Currently it outputs the stripped string in multiples. I would like the output to only list a unique "$workername" to avoid duplicates being listed

```
foreach ($block as $blocks) {
    $worker = $block['pools']['snowgem']['workers'];
    foreach($worker as $workers) {
        //$workers = array_unique($workers);
        $workername = substr($workers['name'], 0, strpos($workers['name'], "."));
        echo $workername."<br>";
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
s1a5Ja3hPfP8FZgABzN8nYSU2uFgKetDTtL
s1a5Ja3hPfP8FZgABzN8nYSU2uFgKetDTtL
s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi
s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi
s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi
s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi
s1djunsw5pgbodthbrq9zGeEyKzDVvpSTEF
s1drJbyRARtXowrj4718TftHDo23RDPmKwr
s1dvGQ5d4pV4bhHBbfTUdvFHjgxgWtexm3d
s1fbJX6RRC4F4L3DxqXAKw8qmXmXw823vV1
s1hfcfXKP6vCBpAHyasEteVDrg3aQMgJZnA
s1hfcfXKP6vCBpAHyasEteVDrg3aQMgJZnA
s1hfcfXKP6vCBpAHyasEteVDrg3aQMgJZnA
```

Dump:

```
Array
(
    [pools] => Array
        (
            [snowgem] => Array
                (
                    [workers] => Array
                        (
                            [s1a5Ja3hPfP8FZgABzN8nYSU2uFgKetDTtL.MESGOrig2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => s1a5Ja3hPfP8FZgABzN8nYSU2uFgKetDTtL.MESGOrig2
                                    [diff] => 35226
                                    [shares] => 21.5
                                    [invalidshares] => 0
                                    [currRoundShares] => 12.9
                                    [currRoundTime] => 53.843
                                    [hashrate] => 307805989.547
                                    [hashrateString] => 615.61 Sol/s
                                    [luckDays] => 0.244
                                    [luckHours] => 5.862
                                    [paid] => 0
                                    [balance] => 0
                                )

                            [s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi.1060X4] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => s1aKn13it5hsXHdUhFUXmp8f2Wj2tqo1CAi.1060X4
                                    [diff] => 986
                                    [shares] => 3.57442495
                                    [invalidshares] => 0
                                    [currRoundShares] => 1.11351463
                                    [currRoundTime] => 103.943
                                    [hashrate] => 51173460.8742
                                    [hashrateString] => 102.35 Sol/s
                                    [luckDays] => 1.469
                                    [luckHours] => 35.260
                                    [paid] => 0
                                    [balance] => 0
                                )
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the input data? It looks like you're pulling `$worker` from the array you're iterating in the foreach instead of the array item at the current iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to store the outputted values, and check if you already outputed this value

```
    $outputed_values = array();
    foreach ($block as $blocks) {
        $worker = $block['pools']['snowgem']['workers'];
        foreach($worker as $workers) {
            //$workers = array_unique($workers);
            $workername = substr($workers['name'], 0, strpos($workers['name'], "."));
            if (!in_array($workername, $outputed_values)){
               echo $workername."<br>";
               array_push($outputed_values, $workername);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Ah, exactly what I needed to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You already had the right function in [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Just store your substrings in an array, then get the unique values and output them.

```
foreach ($block as $blocks) {
    $worker = $block['pools']['snowgem']['workers'];
    foreach($worker as $workers) {
        //$workers = array_unique($workers);
        $workername = substr($workers['name'], 0, strpos($workers['name'], "."));
        $name_array[] = $workername;
    }
    $name_array = array_unqiue($name_array);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($name_array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the outer foreach loop isn't necessary, since there's only one key at the top level. You can just go directly to the nested 'workers' key to get the workers.

```
$workers = $block['pools']['snowgem']['workers'];
```

Then you can use `array_unique` on the list of names you get from that array after reformatting them.

```
$unique_names = array_unique(array_map(function($worker) {
    return substr($worker['name'], 0, strpos($worker['name'], "."));
}, $workers));
```

Comment: Your code will certainly take up less disk space. Can you explain why the outer foreach isn't necessary? Doesn't each block as an index of blocks(just noticed their naming is swapped in the foreach too) have it's own 'pools' key? Not my question, just curious

Comment: @TCooper I believe the var_dump shows a truncated sample of the entire input data, so there aren't actually multiple blocks and pools is a top-level key. But, I certainly could be mistaken :)